# SAS Macro denormalizing by using loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I wonder I can do this in Macro Loop.

For example, this is tableA

```
ID  --  Fruit      --       Count
1       Banana               1
1       Strawberry           2
1       Apple                3
1       Blueberries          4
2       Apple                1
3       Strawberry           1
3       Apple                2
```

I normally do like this not using SAS MACRO

```
proc sql;
select ID,t2.fruit AS fruit1,
          t3.fruit AS fruit2,
          .
          .
          .
from core_table t1
LEFT JOIN TableA t2 on t2.id = t1.id AND t2.count=1 
LEFT JOIN TableA t3 on t3.id = t1.id AND t3.count=2
.
.
.
.
```

so Output is be like

```
ID Fruit1      Fruit2        Fruit3    Fruit4 
1  Banana      Strawberry    Apple     Blueberries          
2  Apple                
3  Strawberry  Apple
```

Basically,Output will denormalise the variables.
SO I am guessing I can do this task by using Do loop, I have been googling around but I can not figure out how to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a macro for something like that. Just use PROC TRANSPOSE.

First let's convert your listing into an actual SAS dataset so we have something to test with.

```
data have ;
  input id fruit :$20. count;
cards;
1       Banana               1
1       Strawberry           2
1       Apple                3
1       Blueberries          4
2       Apple                1
3       Strawberry           1
3       Apple                2  
;
```

Here is the PROC TRANSPOSE code to convert it.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=Fruit;
 by id;
 var fruit;
 id count;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    id    _NAME_    Fruit1        Fruit2        Fruit3      Fruit4

 1      1    fruit     Banana        Strawberry    Apple     Blueberries
 2      2    fruit     Apple
 3      3    fruit     Strawberry    Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

`Proc REPORT` with two `group` variables and an `across` variable will also present the data in the desired output layout.

```
data have;
length fruit $12;
input ID  Fruit $ Count; datalines;
1       Banana               1
1       Strawberry           2
1       Apple                3
1       Blueberries          4
2       Apple                1
3       Strawberry           1
3       Apple                2  
run;

proc report data=have;
  columns ID Fruit,Count;
  define ID / group;
  define Fruit / group;
  define Count / display across ' ' ;
run;
```

[image]